# Keep connection alive using --sysctl with Docker run

Tags: node.js, docker, salesforce, cometd

I currently have a container that is running node services. There code running creates a subscription to the Salesforce Change data capture event bus using CometD. This has been working well but after some time the service will stop receiving events from the Salesforce.

I am thinking this is happening because the alpine Linux container could be marking the connection as broken after data is not received after a while. I have verified that the CometD libraries are creating a connection with keep alive set as true.

Right now I am trying to increase the keep-alive time by running the container with the command:

```
docker run --sysctl net.ipv4.tcp_keepalive_time=10800 --sysctl net.ipv4.tcp_keepalive_intvl=60 --sysctl net.ipv4.tcp_keepalive_probes=20  -p 80:3000 <imageid>
```

My thinking behind this is:

```
net.ipv4.tcp_keepalive_time=10800 
This means that the keepalive routines wait for three hours (1080 secs) 
before sending the first keepalive probe

net.ipv4.tcp_keepalive_intvl=60
Resend the prob every 60 seconds

net.ipv4.tcp_keepalive_probes=20
If no ACK response is received for 20 consecutive times, the connection is 
marked as broken.
```

I guess what I am asking is if this is the correct way to go about running the docker container so that sysctl will run with the settings I have passed in.

I am new to docker, so, I'm sure I did something that doesn't make sense. Thank you for any suggestions.

Comment: You should not configure TCP keepalive (I would leave that at default), because CometD implements an application-level heartbeat that will keep the connection open and not idle even in case of no messages sent or received. You should instead look at who is closing the connection (client or server?) and why (the last CometD message _may_ have some additional information about the error). I would also look into the authentication with SalesForce - make sure it works fine if you're trying to reconnect.

Comment: Thank you! I haven't seen any errors when the connection fails. Thanks for the suggestions. That gives me a good direction to go in. Thank you!!!